# GitHub For Windows sync stuck at 0%

Tags: windows, github

I updated my readme file on the web and the next day, I added some more code. But now that I am trying to sync the commits, it just stays stuck at 0%!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you check the console and see what a `git status`, and a `git push` return?

Comment: I am able to do that but I want to use the GUI